# How to use expect to provide required string when logging into remote computer

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to log into a remote computer that requires a passphrase even though I have ssh set up with private/public keys.  I cannot be made a sudden.  Here is the script I use to do this.

```
⌂107% [:~/bin] develop(+1/-1) ± cat _script
#!/bin/bash
#
#  provide the info to remote-host from this script
#
function _ssh() {
USER=$1
HOST=$2
PSWD=$3

/usr/local/bin/expect<<EOD
   set timeout 30
   log_user 1
   set send_slow {1 .01}
   log_file ~/log/ssh_tmp.log

   send_log "Connecting to $HOST using $USER user\n"
   eval spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=30 "$USER\@$HOST"
   expect {
      timeout {send_user "timeout while connecting to $HOST\n"; exit }
      "*No route to host*" { send_user "$HOST not reachable\n"; exit }
      "*assword: " { send -s $PSWD\r }
      }
   expect {
      timeout { send_user "timeout waiting for prompt\n"; exit }
      "*]#"  { send_user "Login successful to $HOST\n" }
      }
   send "\hostname\r"
   expect {
      "[*~]$"  { send "exit\r" }
      }
   send_user "Disconnected\n"
   close
EOD
}

_ssh remote-userid remote-host 'required-passphrase'
```

---

Here is the response I get:

```
⌂77% [:~/bin] develop(+1/-1) 11s ± _script
spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=30 useid@remote-host
Warning: Permanently added 'remote-host,128.255.155.99' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is a private computing facility. Access to this service is limited to those
who have been granted access by the operating service provider on behalf of the
contracting authority and use is restricted to the purposes for which access was
granted. All access and usage are governed by the terms and conditions of access
agreed to by all registered users and are thus subject to the provisions of the
Computer Misuse Act, 1990 under which unauthorised use is a criminal offence.

If you are not authorised to use this service you must disconnect immediately.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

userid@remote-host's password: 

Welcome to remote-host-name

Website: https://remote-host/

Documentation: https://remote-host/en/master/

Last login: Sat Dec 10 10:16:03 2021 from my-ip
[userid@remote-host ~]$ ls      (I entered this, when the [userid@remote-host ~]$ appeared)
timeout waiting for prompt
```

It appears to log me in and show me the prompt, but is it expecting something else?  How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Just what it says: "timeout waiting for prompt"

```
   expect {
      timeout { send_user "timeout waiting for prompt\n"; exit }
      "*]#"  { send_user "Login successful to $HOST\n" }
      }
```

Change the prompt pattern to `-re {\][$#] $}` to match a close bracket followed by *either* `#` (root) *or* `$` (you), followed by a space at the end.

Since you'll expect the prompt in several places, store it in a variable

```
   set prompt {\][$#] $}
   expect {
      timeout { send_user "timeout waiting for prompt\n"; exit }
      -re prompt
   }
   send_user "Login successful to $HOST\n"
```

---

Adding an expect program into a bash script, use a **quoted here-doc** and pass the shell variables to expect through the environment: this is important because you don't want the shell to expand your expect variables and you don't want to have to start escaping thing.

```sh
function _ssh() {
export USER=$1
export HOST=$2
export PSWD=$3

/usr/local/bin/expect << 'EOD'
...
   send_log "Connecting to $env(HOST) using $env(USER) user\n"
```

---

spawn does not need eval:

```
  spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=30 "$env(USER)@$env(HOST)"
```

---

Change `close` to `expect eof` to allow the ssh connection to end gracefully.

---

Lastly, your expect code is doing all the interaction with the ssh process. You won't be able to type at the remote prompt unless you instruct expect to cede control of the ssh process to the user. You use the `interact` command to do that.

Comment: Thanks,  I tried the above as I understood it, but I could not get it to work.  First, what do you mean by the 'interact' command?  Secondly, the $env(HOST), etc. were rejected as not being defined.  With my method above, it logs in and then issues a promt.  At that point it times out no matter what I do. How do I use the 'interact' command?

Comment: Do you understand that it's timing out because your actual prompt is not matching the pattern? Did you adjust the pattern?

Comment: I adjusted the pattern using the prompt variable as you suggested, but now the password is not supplied and it just waits forever for a password.

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the expect code, and the verbose debug output will indicate why your patterns don't match.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I think my problem is the sequence of lines:
Welcome to remote-host-name

Website: https://remote-host/

Documentation: https://remote-host/en/master/

Last login: Sat Dec 10 10:16:03 2021 from my-ip
The come before the prompt.  How to I handle those.

Comment: Show the debug output in the question.

Comment: This is currently my prompt:  set prompt {\~\]\$}

expect: timed out


[woo@cirrus-login1 ~]$ 
expect: does "[woo@cirrus-login1 ~]$ " (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression "prompt"? Gate "prompt"? gate=no
expect: timed out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240107/discussion-between-john-wooten-and-glenn-jackman).